# Permission_Denied [google cloud platform]: This API method requires billing to be enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

I am using Google Cloud platform's vision API
to request the API. I am using the API key provided by them
[authentication documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/auth) in this link. I am authenticating using the API key when I POST URL along with the API Key the following response arrived.

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "This API method requires billing to be enabled. Please 
                 enable billing on project santram-194814 by visiting 
                 https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enable?
                 project=[my-project-name] then retry. If you enabled 
                 billing for this project recently, wait a few minutes for 
                 the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
          {
          "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
          "links": [
                 {
                  "description": "Google developers console billing",
                  "url": 
                 "https://console.developers.google.com/billing/enableproject=[my-project-name]"
      }
    ]
  }
]
  }
}
```

I cross checked my Console's Billing panel and it shows me:

```
Your payment information could not be processed. Visit the payment overview page to make sure your payment information is up to date and to pay any outstanding charges.
```

I am using the same sample application in my home machine It works fine

but I got this error in setting up another machine

Comment: Are you using the same account and user from both machines that you use to connect to the GCP project?

Are you on free trial? 
Is free trial over?
If you're not on free trial and you have a paying account:
Are you behind on payments?
Check if you have unpayed bills and/or if your credit card number is not correctly set within your billing account.
It seems there is either some missing information from your billing account settings or there is some trouble with payments.

Comment: i use same account ..with same project...plus i m using free trial

Comment: Then you should check if the credit card that you've set in the billing settings is correctly set.

If this does not help, you can directly contact Google Cloud Support team, since Free Trial customers can request free technical support [1] for the duration of the trial, this way you can directly let the billing team the issues that you're experiencing.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/#options

Comment: hi Paula, thanx for your support i would like to inform you that my debit card that i entered it for billing in gcp is not valid..it shows me "Your payment information could not be processed. Visit the payment overview page to make sure your payment information is up to date and to pay any outstanding charges" on console billing page .still i can perform api requests on my  home computer to the google cloud vision api...but when i try to implement the same project with same API key with same account...it shows me the error of billing...

Comment: The credit card/bank account is required to verify your identity:
https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial

As you probably know, if you're on free trial you get 12-month and $300 during free trial.

You can set the credit card to make use of the Cloud Visio API and you will not be charged or billed during your free trial.

I link here this documentation where you can check an example of use for Cloud Vision API and the charges that apply in the example:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing#example

Comment: Please keep in mind that free trial was shrunk to **[90-day**, $300 Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the documentation [90-day, $300 Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial):

> The 90-day, $300 Free Trial period starts automatically when you
> complete your signup.
>
> To complete your Free Trial signup, **you must provide a credit card or
> other payment method to set up a Cloud Billing account and verify your
> identity**.

Also, have a look at the error message:

> Your payment information could not be processed. Visit the payment
> overview page to make sure your payment information is up to date and
> to pay any outstanding charges.

**To solve you issue** you should update your payment information, as it was suggested by *@Shibboleet* in the comment section.

Furthermore, [90-day, $300 Free Trial](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-trial) have some limitations that described in Program coverage.